# Can't find syntax to split JSON array in Apache Camel using jsonpath

Tags: apache-camel, jsonpath

I have an incoming string that is a JSON array and want to process each element in the array. The array contains objects, e.g. [{ "title": "book 1"}, { "title": "book 2"}]

Code looks like:

```
        // code that returned string here...
        .log("body: ${body}") // got JSON string
        .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)

    // .split().jsonpath("$") entire array
    // .split().jsonpath("$.") blows up
    // .split().jsonpath("$[]") blows up
    // .split().jsonpath("$.[]") blows up
    // .split().jsonpath("$.[*]") fail

        .split().jsonpath("what do I put here?") // how to pass each bit of the array?

        .to("direct:book");

    from("direct:book")
        .log("book ${body}") 
    ;
```

How can I process each element of the array one by one?

Comment: Found another way to do this, giving up on jsonpath https://github.com/poggs/json-array-splitter

Answer (score 0):

first split array and after execute json path

```
    .log("body: ${body}") 
            .split().body()
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
       // you have n items in there 
        // setProperty("name",jsonpath("$.name")) 
.end();
```

Comment: Thanks for having a look, but I think we are both just wasting our time with jsonpath. The above splits the content on all the commas. I updated the question with example data.